# Right way to update state with react socket hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am a beginner to react and I feel this question has been asked several times in the past but I can't see to understand what I am missing to get this working.

I am writing a simple browser based game. I am using socket-io to connect to the server and I am using a custom hook for obtaining state sent by the server

```
  export const useSocketState = (serverUrl: string) => {
    const [isConnected, setConnected] = useState(false)
    const [socketId, setSocketId] = useState('')
    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(DEFAULT_INITIAL_STATE)
    useEffect(() => {
      const client = socket.connect(serverUrl)
      client.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected with id " + client.id)
        setConnected(true)
        setSocketId(client.id)
      });
      client.on("disconnect", () => {
        setConnected(false)
      });
      client.on("gameStateUpdate", (data: ClientGameState) => {
        console.dir("Recieved new state from server" + data);
        console.dir("GameState is " + gameState);
        setGameState(prevState => {
          const newState = data
          console.log(" new state is " + newState)
          return newState
        })
      });
    }, gameState);

    return {gameState, isConnected, socketId}
  }
```

I am using this hook in a component where I am referrring to the gameState returned by this hook.

I am expecting that when server sends a new state my gameState is actually set with a new state. I do see the log statement where a newState is printed when the server returns a new state but I am not seeing it being reflected in the component I am using.

```
Game component

  import React from "react";
  import {useSocketState} from "./useSocket";
  import {ClientGameState} from "../game/GameState";

  export function GameComponent(props: any) {
  const {gameState, isConnected, socketId} = useSocketState("http://127.0.0.1:8080");

    if (gameState.state === 'created') {
      return (

        <div>
          <p> Game id for this game: {props.location.state.gameId} and playerId:  {props.location.state.playerId} </p>
          <p>{JSON.stringify(gameState)}</p>
        </div>

      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <p> Game state is not created </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: The return type of the callback from `gameStateUpdate` is correct, right? Does it match `gameState`?

Comment: yes both are of types ClientGameState.

Answer (score 0):

```
 export const useSocketState = (serverUrl: string) => {
    const [isConnected, setConnected] = useState(false)
    const [socketId, setSocketId] = useState('')
    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(DEFAULT_INITIAL_STATE);

    function socketConnection(){
      const client = socket.connect(serverUrl)
      client.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected with id " + client.id)
        setConnected(true)
        setSocketId(client.id)
      });
      client.on("disconnect", () => {
        setConnected(false)
      });
      client.on("gameStateUpdate", (data: ClientGameState) => {
        console.dir("Recieved new state from server" + data);
        console.dir("GameState is " + gameState);
        setGameState(prevState => {
          const newState = data
          console.log(" new state is " + newState)
          return newState
        })
      });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      socketConnection();
    }, []);

    return {gameState, isConnected, socketId}
  }
```

When you connect to the socket, you don't need to use `useEffect()` anymore.

Comment: Tried this, did not work! I have pasted my component code on the top if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Socket connection needed be made when component is mounted. So, you'll need second parameter of useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ... connection
}, []) // run on component mount
```

You may also use `useEffect` when some variable changes:

```
useEffect(() => { // additional useEffect hook
  // ... changes being detected
}, [gameState])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just passing the data that is returned from the socket to your setGameState hook.

```
client.on("gameStateUpdate", (data: ClientGameState) => {
    setGameState(data);
  });
```

Comment: Let me test this out. One min.

Comment: If you console.log(gameState) after running setGameState what do you see?

Comment: I put a console.log before and after the setGameState and it prints the DEFAULT_INITIAL_STATE  that I set.

Comment: I got it to work on this end. You shouldn't have any issues after returning the data you received to your hook. My suggestion would be for you to add some console logs line by line to really dissect whats going on line by line.

Comment: Try this, remove the third client.on method and replace it with the following: let newState;

client.on("gameStateUpdate", (data: ClientGameState) => {
  console.dir("Recieved new state from server" + data);
  console.dir("GameState is " + gameState);
  newState = data;
  console.log(data);
  
});

setGameState( newState);